# Seaborn jointplot annotate with correlation

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jointplot

Before the release of the latest seaborn version, I was able to use the following to annotate my plot with the pearson Rho.

Using the latest version I am unable to find a way to do the same as `#ax.annotate(stats.pearsonr)` throws an error.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import scipy.stats as stat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns

X = np.random.rand(10,2)

df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['v1', 'v2'])

a = df.v1.values
b = a*2 + a**5

print("The Rho is {}".format(np.corrcoef(a,b)[0][1]))

ax = sns.jointplot(a, b, kind='reg',color='royalblue')
#ax.annotate(stats.pearsonr)
ax.ax_joint.scatter(a,b)
ax.set_axis_labels(xlabel='a', ylabel='b', size=15)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Old output that I cannot get anymore:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sns.jointplot` doesn't return an `ax`, but a [`JointGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid). You can use `ax_joint`, `ax_marg_x`, and `ax_marg_y` as normal matplotlib axes to make changes to the subplots, such as adding annotations.

Here is an example using axis fraction coordinates for positioning.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns

a = np.random.rand(10)
b = a * 2 + a ** 5

print("The Rho is {}".format(np.corrcoef(a, b)[0][1]))

g = sns.jointplot(x=a, y=b, kind='reg', color='royalblue')
# ax.annotate(stats.pearsonr)
r, p = stats.pearsonr(a, b)
g.ax_joint.annotate(f'$\\rho = {r:.3f}, p = {p:.3f}$',
                    xy=(0.1, 0.9), xycoords='axes fraction',
                    ha='left', va='center',
                    bbox={'boxstyle': 'round', 'fc': 'powderblue', 'ec': 'navy'})
g.ax_joint.scatter(a, b)
g.set_axis_labels(xlabel='a', ylabel='b', size=15)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]